# Difference between polysemes and senses

Tags: terminology, words, synonymy, word-sense-disambiguation, polysemy

As far as I understand, saying that two words are polysemes is saying they're synonymous homonyms, but not synonymous enough to be the same word. Senses on the other hand, are synonymous enough to be counted as variations of the same word.

Perhaps it is not the degree of synonymy that is the distinguisher, but rather the nature of the synonymy? Perhaps senses are variations of a word's definition depending on context, whereas polysemes arise from the metaphorical usage of words?

So, *murder* can mean "partaking in any action leading to the death of an organism" in common parlance (one context), and mean "intentionally make a person die" in legalese (another context). One is in fact a generalization of the other (if that's important).

Whereas *pig* can mean *the animal pig*, or it can mean *person that acts in a disgusting way*; one is in no way the other, but has arisen from analogy and symbolism.

Comment: As far as I understand, _polysemy_ is not a relation between two words like _synonymy_, but rather a condition of a single word that has many meanings. So definitions don't start by "saying that two words are **polysemes**". I've never heard that word before, especially not in the plural.

Comment: Indeed. The OED defines _polyseme_ as "  A word or lexical unit that has several or multiple meanings". Using this definition, your explication is flawed: _Saying two wards are polysemes_ is incoherent.